# Silverstripe - How to add a new action to the existing controller

Tags: php, silverstripe

AccountPage_Controller under core_shop module has defined some actions
under /account url.

I want to add a new action under /account, how can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't said which version of SilverStripe framework or cms you're using. Assuming v3 or above and depending on your scenario, using custom `Extension` subclasses known as "Decorators" is prob the best way to go.

- Decorate `AccountPage_Controller` by creating your own custom controller with the desired custom action and `$allowed_actions` static
- Reference your custom controller in an `extensions` block in your `config.yml`
- run dev/build flush=all